# Automatically execute bash script under the privileges of another user

Tags: linux, bash, script, sudo, privileges

Is there a way to execute a bash script under the privileges of another user (automatically)?
I think "sudo" is the right way, but I don't know how to automate the process.

E.g. I want to run something like this (user "bla" runs a process under "blub"):

```
sudo <the user under which i want to run the process> <path to script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So did I get that right.

User "bla" wants to run a command as User "blub" ?

Then something like this could work:

```
sudo -u blub /path/to/command
```

If you need this to be done without being asked for a password add the follwing line to /etc/sudoers (via visudo command):

```
bla    ALL=(blub) NOPASSWD: /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 3):

you can work with SUID and SGID bit permissions ([note that this may be really dangerous](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html))

give the permissions to execute this file to a group that the user you are executing the script as belong to, and set via SUID anyone who runs this script to run it as the user who owns the script

```
sudo chmod 4751 /path/to/my/file
sudo chgrp somegroup /path/to/my/file
```

Then, you just need to execute the script as **userB** who is member of **somegroup** and it will be executed with as **userA** and **somegroup**

```
ls -l /path/to/my/file
-rwsr-xr-- userA somegroup /path/to/my/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run a script from a cgi. My script generates some directories and files, and I needed them to be owned by nagios user. This is what I did:

```
edit /etc/sudoers using visudo command
apache   ALL=(nagios) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/pangoo_lib/change_state_simulation
```

From my cgi (apache user), the script is run:

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/local/nagios/libexec/pangoo_lib/change_state_simulation
```